# Different action/event on checkbox selection and node selection in p tree primefaces

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a requirement in which I have to call two different actions on p tree checkbox selection and node selection. In checkbox selection, I don't want the node to be selected and highlighted as grey and I want multiple checkbox selection which should only select the checkboxes. In node selection, I want single node selection and it should be highlighted as grey.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have any code?

Comment: I have no clue what to use. I am using ajax select event on node select..but it is selecting the whole node along with checkbox.

<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{projectTreeManagedBean.onSelect}" process="@this"> </p:ajax>